# How to get a children element from object

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I am getting data from backend, once that is applied to template using my template function like this :

```
this.render = function() {
        var html = Mustache.render(self.template.base.html());

        self.el.parent.html(html);
        self.el.panel = $('.header-panel', self.el.parent);

        console.log ( self.el.panel );

    };
```

My "self.el.panel" (consoled) giving me the result like this:

```
  0: div.header-panel.flex-right
    context: document
    length: 1
    prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]
    selector: "#header .header-panel"
```

From this data, how can i find a child elements?

I tried like this, but no luck..

```
console.log ( $("a", self.el.panel) );
```

even like this:

```
console.log ( $(self.el.panel).find('a') );
```

any one help me to get the child elements..

Comment: try: $('.header-panel').children('a');

Comment: even i tried like so. but i could get element.

Comment: `"a"` is not there in the consoled log.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code sample, `self.el.panel` is a jQuery object.

Therefore...

```
self.el.panel = $('.header-panel', self.el.parent);

// ...

var childA = self.el.panel.children("a");
var descendantA = self.el.panel.find("a");
```

If that does not give you anything, then there are no `<a>` elements in that section (or not *at that time*).

Comment: You are 100% correct. at the time of finding the element, i did not render the children of "a". thanks very much.